# Excel Data validation list with array formula

Tags: excel, unique, dropdown

I have a table with duplicated values in a column. How can I use this column, to provide unique values as a dropdown options in another cell? I want to be able to enter new rows in my table that might include already existing or new values and dropdown should automatically reflect this.

What I tried with UNIQUE(MyTable[MyColumn]):

- Excel is not accepting this formula as a data validation source
- I can spill UNIQUE(MyTable[MyColumn]) to range and name this range and use it as a data validation source, but the named range will not expand/contract automatically when my table data change
- Excel will not accept UNIQUE(MyTable[MyColumn]) in a new table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right way - and yes: this is annoying and definitly not intuitiv.

You have to add a # after the reference to your range when naming it:

[image]

Then use the name for your validation list. It will now expand when you add a new row to the table.

D3: UNIQUE-Formula referencing the table-column
Name "lstValues": referencing $D$3#
then use lstValues

Comment: For some reason Excel is not happy with # at he end of the range reference. It will accept named range but it won't allow to use it anywhere

Comment: The cell (!) you are referencing for the name contains the UNIQUE-Formula?
Regarding the screenshot: see my update on answer

Comment: Ok, I know where my error was. I was entering # after the entire spill (D3:D8# in your screen). It should only be first value - D3#. Now Excel accepts =IstValues as a Data Validation source. I will be posting alternative answer that I came up in the meantime, but this works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative solution**

- Insert Power Query referencing original table as a source: `= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="MyTable"]}[Content]`
- *RMB* on a column to keep, *Remove Other Columns* (if any)
- *RMB* on a column, *Remove Duplicates*
- *Close and Load* to the sheet as a table, name table `DropdownTable`
- Define new named range `DropdownValues` with reference to `=DropdownTable` (or `=DropdownTable[#All]` to include header)
- Use `=DropdownValues` as a data validation source