# Excel XLOOKUP / FILTER Function Unable to Use in Data Validation Drop Down List

Tags: excel, vba, filter, xlookup

I am truly stumped and believe I'm looking at the cliff of what excel is simply incapable of in its current state. I am hoping that one of you geniuses can prove me wrong.

Here's my situation. I have thousands of items that need to be sorted by 5+ parameters. The best way I can think to do this is to have one drop down list populate the next drop down list.

For instance;

A user would select the first drop down list and choose a given item.

**1. ITEM**

- From that item chosen, the next drop down list would populate to only show the various model numbers for that item.

**2. MODEL**

I currently have this part working using an XLOOKUP embedded in a data validation list.
`=XLOOKUP(Item Input Cell, Item Column, Model Number Column)`

After this point. I want XLOOKUP to continue to automatically populate these lists.

**3. MATERIAL**

**4. CAPACITY**

**5. VENDOR**

**6. PRICE**

From the chosen item & model, then materials that match both item & model display in a drop down. Capacities that match 1,2,3 have a drop down, vendors that match 1,2,3,4 have a drop down, and finally displaying all possible prices for that input in a drop down.

My problem is that I can not seem to figure out how to use XLOOKUP sorting by 2+ criteria successfully in a data validation list. I get the "There's a problem with this formula" error box.

I have scoured the internet for others encountering this problem, but nothing seems quite 1 to 1 to what I am working with. I am unable to have an independent table on this specific excel sheet to then populate the data validation list for every single permutation so that's out.

For list **3**, I have tried using

`=XLOOKUP((ItemInputCell & ModelInputCell),(ItemColumn & ModelColumn),MaterialColumn)`

- this does not work and leads to the aforementioned error box.
  FILTER does work when it's in a regular cell, but is unable to function in a data validation list (?) apparently. Which is truthfully aggravating as it's functioning perfectly otherwise.

I am hoping that one of you can see some novice mistake and correct my ways OR if I have reached the cliff I mentioned, what is another method of doing this?

Comment: Might be easier to help with screens shots. What you have, what'd you expect, etc.

Comment: Note that XLOOKUP returns the first found value only. Don't you mean to use FILTER instead? Have the formula in a different Sheet (let's say `Sheet2!A2`) and refer to it in your dropdown as `Sheet2!$A$2#`

Comment: @pgSystemTester Sorry, I wish I could but it's for my job. Did I do a poor job explaining it?

Comment: @P.b why would XLOOKUP work for the first drop down (and populate the whole list accurately) if it's for the first found? Is there not a way to make it display all for multiple permuations? It's displaying all the options currently.

I have tried your second and was really hoping that's not the only option. The problem with this sheet is that, in practice, new lines will be added and new rows created. I'm not exactly sure how that would link with tables in a different row. But I'm also running into problems where =FILTER can not be used in tables in any capacity and getting a !SPILL error.

Comment: You don't need tables when using `FILTER`. Sharing a reproducible sample would be helpful

Comment: Look at this answer from Ike that probably helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/68742273/12634230

Comment: @HR-32091-24, uh... yea not the best job of explaining. You don't need to post any work details, just creatively substitute in some dummy data that mimics your issue and post as sample google sheet or use [a mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Ten rows of data is usually enough to trouble shoot.